# two project with 2.4.6 play framework, they didn't share session(cookie) , key&domain are the same in both the projects; ;

Tags: java, session, cookies, playframework

[image]

I've tried deploy on the server&localhost;
  but the session didn't share with each other;
  i start the two projects on the same domain with different ports

Comment: domain is “.mydomain.com”

Comment: May be you have different encryption key, so session can't be decrypted